# Find a value in a field based on matching a different field in the table with that in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do something really simple but am having a lot of trouble.
I have two tables one structured with the following fields

```
member.tx_nickname var(100)
member.accountnumber int

memtransactions.accountnumber (FK uniqueidentifier)
```

what I want to do is lookup member table and find the nickname in the member table for the record where member.accountnumber = memtransactions.accountnumber

I have tried a few but i keep getting errors with field type conflicts

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT member.tx_nickname
FROM member m
JOIN memtransactions mt ON m.accountnumber = mt.accountnumber
```

Comment: ty bobs but I get the folowing error Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Comment: @Ian Robson, I didn't notice before that the data type for accountnumber is different in each table.  That's why the query fails.  is this intentionally different?

Comment: It is just we need the field in memtransactions to be a unique identifier and it is just a normal integer in the member database. I thought the uniqueidentifier was an integer but obviously not.

Comment: That's correct.  uniqueidentifier is not an integer.  You might want to look at the IDENTITY column property to help auto-generate unique integer values.